Does $\varphi, \varphi^{-1}f$ convex imply $f$ convex?
I have been reading through Linear Analysis by B. Bollobás, and I was unsure about one of the exercises for the first chapter.

Let $f:(a,b) \to (c,b)$ and $\varphi:(c,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1} f$ are convex. Show that $f$ is convex.

I think I have a counterexample with:
$$f : (0,1) \to (0,1), x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$$
$$\varphi : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto - \log(x)$$
$$ \varphi^{-1} : \mathbb{R} \to (0,1), x \mapsto e^{-x}$$
Is there an error in the book? Was a different question intended?
It is easy to prove the result when $\varphi$ is increasing, but then it is a trivial corollary of an earlier question. I’m not sure why the domain and range of $f$ are constrained to have the same right endpoint either.

As far as I can tell, your counterexample holds, so there must be an error in the question

Your counterexample has one slight flaw, which is rather a philosophical thing than an actual error: The image of $\varphi$, so $\varphi((0,1))$ in your case is not $\mathbb R$ but only $(0, \infty)$. Hence $\varphi^{-1}$ is also only defined on $(0, \infty)$. Maybe for the question to work you need a function which is onto $\mathbb R$; although I am not sure about that.

@Lukas Perhaps, although the question is very poorly-written if that is what was intended. I think there is probably also a counterexample for that too, but I will need to think a bit about that.

@Lukas If we require $\varphi$ to be surjective on $\Bbb R$, then in order for $\varphi$ to be convex we must allow either $a=-\infty$ or $b=\infty$. In this case, with $(a,b)=(0,\infty)$, the counterexample still holds. (In the special case where $a=-\infty$ and $b$ is finite, $\varphi$ is forced to be increasing, so I guess then the claim would hold)

Can anyone prove the the assertion itself?
